# Duvida simples sobre esse uso de Decorator em c#

Tags: c#

estou aprendendo a usar o padrao decorator em c#, e esta tudo fluindo muito bem
exeto por um UNICO questionamento que faz o autor deste exemplo, mas isso esta me incomodando muito pois reviro o codigo varias vezes e nao entendo o porque de tal afirmaçao. É o seguinte, neste exemplo aqui:

http://www.macoratti.net/13/02/net_decor1.htm

ao final o autor afirma o seguinte:

"Qualquer opcional pode ser usado para decorar qualquer carro, desde que o carro específico implemente um tipo Carro e o opcional especifico implemente o tipo DecoratorCarro."

inclusive DecoratorCarro esta em negrito..

o intrigante é: vc poe completamente tirar a classe DecoratorCarro e que ela nao tem utilidade nenhuma, codigo funciona do mesmo jeito basta as classes opcionais herdar diretamente de carro e eu nao entendo porque a enfase e a razao de existencia de DecoratorCarro

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJgn.jpg. Se não tivesse utilidade não precisaria existir. Só está funcionando porque não está usando o padrão de fato. O exemplo lá pode não ser bom. O pior é que quase todos exemplos de DP são ruins, em geral porque a pessoa leu em algum lugar o que é, escreve e não sabe bem como aplicá-lo, não consegue dar um exemplo mais claro. E aí fica todo mundo de língua pra fora querendo usar sem nem entender. E por isso eu não respondo, eu cometeria o mesmo erro. Não me lembro de um caso que ousei esse DP, pelo menos desse jeito exato. Estude mais o padrão e verá utilidade.